# Generate set of API timings from CSV

Tags: python, statistics

I have a list of APIs with their corresponding execution time in the following format:

```
findByNameWithProduct, 108
findProductByPartNumber, 140
findProductById, 178
findByName, 99
findProductsByCategory, 260
findByNameWithCategory, 103
findByNameWithCategory, 108
findByNameWithCategory, 99
findByNameWithProduct, 20
findProductById, 134
findTopCategories, 54
findByName, 48
findSubCategories, 44
findProductByPartNumber, 70
findProductByPartNumber, 63
```

What I am trying to do is for each unique API, store the minimum, maximum, average, and 90th percentile execution times but am unsure how to do this. I've thought of using a Dictionary and I can detect if an API already is entered but as far as I know, a dictionary is just a name value pair, not multiple entries. I've been playing with something like this but I know it's not efficient (plus it doesn't work). I'm not too familiar with data structures in Python - does anyone know a clean way to accomplish this?

```
counter = 0
uniqueAPINames = set(apiNames)
for uniqueAPIName in uniqueAPINames :
    for line in lines:
        if uniqueAPIName in line:
            print line
                    #Somehow add all these up...
    counter = counter + 1
```

EDIT:

With help from the accepted answer, here is the solution:

```
tests = []
lines = []
files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder)]
for f in files:
    if '-data.log' in f:
        fi = open(folder + '/' + f, 'r')
        lines = lines + fi.readlines()
        fi.close()
        for line in lines:
            if ('Thread' not in line):
                lineSplit = line.strip().split(',')
                testNumber = lineSplit[2].strip()
                testName = apiData[testNumber]
                testTime = lineSplit[4].strip()
                testList = [testName, testTime]
                tests.append(testList)

d = {}
for test in tests:
    if test[0] in d:
        d[test[0]].append(test[1])
    else:
        d[test[0]] = [test[1]]

for key in d:
    print 'API Name: ' + str(key)
    d[key] = [int(i) for i in d[key]]
    d[key].sort(key=int)
    print 'Min: ' + str(d[key][0])
    print 'Max: ' + str(d[key][-1])
    print 'Average: ' + str(sum(d[key]) / len(d[key]))
    print '90th Percentile: ' + str(sum(d[key]) / len(d[key]) * .90)
```

Comment: I don't think your computation for the 90th percentile is right.  It looks like you're just taking the average and multiplying that by 0.90, whereas you want (roughly) `d[key][int(0.9 * len(d[key]))]`, i.e. the value below which 90% of the values fall.  You'll have to check the formal def'n to see how the boundary cases and rounding are supposed to work, I can never remember.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I wasn't 100% confident in that percentile calculation but didn't have time to research it until now. I found this which seems to do the trick: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with a dictionary.  Values can be anything, and in this case a list makes sense:

```
d = {}
for api_name, runtime in whatever:
    if api_name in d:  # we've seen it before
        d[api_name].append(runtime)
    else:  # first time
        d[api_name] = [runtime]  # list with one entry
```

Now you have a dict mapping an API name to a list of all runtimes.  The rest is clear?  I'd sort each list, after which finding min, max and percentiles are all very easy.

```
for runtimes in d.itervalues():
    runtimes.sort()
```

is all it takes to sort all the dict's runtime lists in-place.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand conceptually what you are getting at - can you please explain what type of object "whatever" is? I'm reading the API names and execution times from a file so I've been maintaining two lists (each with the same length) so I can manually retrieve the times. I'm not sure how I can combine them into the same object and iterate through them.

Comment: On some more studying, I am able to get your solution to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: If they're the same length, the easiest way is:

`for api_name, runtime in zip(list_of_names, list_of_runtimes):`